# Oracle: generate a numeric sequence whose values start with a certain digit

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I need to define a numeric sequence for a column of my table in Oracle.
The only contraint I've been given requires all values to start with 9.
So, the list of autogenerated values should start like the following:

9, 90, 91, 92...99, 900, 901...999, 9000, 9001...9999, 90000,...

Any idea about how to solve this problem via SQL (by creating opportunely and editing by sequence) and/or by Java code?
In some posts I've read on web, people suggest to modify sequence this way:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE gokhan.sample_seq INCREMENT BY -500;
SELECT gokhan.sample_seq.NEXTVAL FROM dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE gokhan.sample_seq INCREMENT BY 1;
```

This requires the computation of new increment every time. If possible, I'd like to write a portion of SQL code that automates such process.

Thanks for support.

Comment: This sounds like a homework exercise. What additional constraints are there?

Comment: can't you just use a sequence and add a 9 as first digit to it? like CONCAT('9',sequence.nextval)?

Comment: Sadly, it's not an exercise, but luckly there's no other constraint. Regarding your hint, is it possible to concatenate a string with a numeric value and save result into a numeric column?

Answer (score 1):

The only difficulty I see if you want to implement it in java is to calculate the next value for a given number. But luckily your borders are the powers of ten (10, 100, 1000 ...) otherwise you increment by one. Something like the following should give you an initial approach

```
public class Test {

//A method to check if a given number is a power of ten :

    public static boolean powerOf10(int n) {
        int max_power10 = 1_000_000_000;
        if (n > max_power10 ) return false;
        int i = 1;
        while (i < n) i *= 10;   
        return i == n;
    }

 //Then you can calculate the next value by either adding one or 
 //adding one and multipling by 9 if last value plus one is a power of ten

    public static int nextVal(int lastVal){        
        if(!powerOf10(lastVal + 1)){
            return lastVal + 1;
        }
        return 9 * (lastVal + 1);
    }

//Note: for the sake of readability i omitted the check if the last value is a valid value (a number starting with 9)

//Demo 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int MIN_VALUE = 9;
        for(int i = MIN_VALUE; i < 10000; i = nextVal(i)){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is more or less what I had in mind on Java side.
How would you act on database sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Use normal sequence 0,1,2,3,... and for any *x* retrieved from this sequence compute the mapped element of your fancy sequence directly.

When initial value of sequence is 0, then elements 1-10 map to 90-99, elements 11-110 to 900-999, elements 111-1110 to 9000-9999 etc. Hence for each *x* of input sequence (for example 500) find the lower bound of the interval (111), compute peer of lower bound (900) and compute offset of peer (9389).

Code:

```sql
with sequence (x) as (
  select level - 1 from dual connect by level < 1001
), o (x,ones) as (
  select x, case x when 0 then 0 else to_number(rpad('1',to_char(1 + trunc(log(10,x))),'1')) end as ones
  from sequence
), m (x,ones,min) as (
  select x, ones, case when x >= ones then ones else (ones - 1) / 10 end as min 
  from o
)
select x, case x when 0 then 9 else x - min + 9 * power(10, 1 + trunc(log(10,min))) end as result from m;
```

Translating to PLSQL is up to you. Note the proposal of concatenating `9` to digits of normal sequence doesn't produce required result since such sequence would grow 10/9 times quicker (number of digits would increase by 1 after 9,90,900,... elements whereas in your sequence the number of digits increases by 1 after 10,100,1000,... elements). It would be lots simpler though. Despite you didn't describe reasons for such a logic, I would consider replacing by simpler logic anyway.